# Sending one event from one activity to multiple fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, communication, fragment

I'd like my activity to send the same event to multiple fragment. Instead of making my activity calling each individual fragment method  : `FragmentA.DoTask()`, `FragmentB.DoTask()`, `FragmentC.DoTask()`, etc... I'd like rather make my activity send only one event and then make the fragment listening to this event.

On the developpers docs they make the activity "listen" to the fragment but then the activity calls the fragments' methods. Is it possible the other way around : to make the fragments "listen" to the activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way around it. The word "listen" in the docs is more metaphorical. You have to call all fragments explicitly.

The closet thing you can get, is to have a list of Fragment maintained in your Activity class. e.g.: create a customized Fragment class:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
  public abstract void doTask();
}
```

Have all your Fragments inherited from this class.

```
public class FragmentA extends MyFragment{

  @Override
  public void doTask(){
    //exec code here

  }
}
```

In your Activity class, each time you create a Fragment, add it to a List too. When the event occurs, call all Fragments.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  List<myFragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<MyFragment>();

  public void addFragment(MyFragment fragment){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
  }

  public void onEvent(){
    for(MyFragment fragment:mFragmentList){
      fragment.doTask();
    }
  }

}
```

Note: If you don't have that many Fragments, this solution can be a overkill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got a problem (JavanullPointerexeption). I think it's because I don't instantiate the interface. On Developpers Doc, they instanciate the interface in  "onAttach". It's OK in a fragment but what should I do in the Activity class ? onAttach doesn't exist there.

Comment: @Jecimi Sorry I was misleading you. This is not working. Let me think about it when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

You could Use **EventBus** system.

Description on [RRiBbit](http://www.rribbit.org/eventbus.html) (though this library not related to Android) define it precisely:

> An Eventbus is a mechanism that allows different components to
>   communicate with each other without knowing about each other. A
>   component can send an Event to the Eventbus without knowing who will
>   pick it up or how many others will pick it up. Components can also
>   listen to Events on an Eventbus, without knowing who sent the Events.
>   That way, components can communicate without depending on each other.
>   Also, it is very easy to substitute a component. As long as the new
>   component understands the Events that are being sent and received, the
>   other components will never know.
>
> So what exactly is a component here? Well, a component could be
>   anything. In most Eventbuses, they are Java Objects. They send Events
>   and they also listen to Events.

In Android you can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).